# nginx won't use 100% cpu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

i'm just benchmarking a default install of nginx trying to get it to serve as many requests per second as possible. i expected it to use 100% cpu under load like other webservers do, but i can't get it to use more than about 40%.

i tried on Ubuntu and Manjaro with the same results.

`ab -k -c 500 -n 1000000 http://localhost/` is getting about 150,000 requests per second. i imagine it could serve at least twice as much if it used the full cpu but i can't figure out how. it's just serving the default nginx html page.

i've made sure to use these settings:

```
access_log off;
worker_processes auto;
worker_connections 1024;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
gzip on;
expires 365d;
```

Comment: I'd ask this over on ServerFault, and ask how you can profile the process to figure out what's blocking.

Comment: @Brad ok, i forgot sites other than stackoverflow exist